# MVT Question Calculus Past Paper

Tags: calculus

Trouble answering this question:

Suppose that $0<a<b<\frac\pi2$. 
Show that $\tan(b)-\tan(a)>b-a>\sin(b)-\sin(a)$

Can I just take any $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the inequality or do I need to keep them as $a,b$ and prove algebraically.

Any help is appreciated many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divide through by $b-a$ and apply the mean value theorem to the functions $\tan x$ and $\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to prove it for all $a,b$ satisfying the inequality you are given. You should be able to prove each half of the inequality using MVT.

Answer (score 0):

For the right half, pick $f = \sin$. Thus, for any $a,b \exists c s.t$:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$
$$\cos c = \frac{\sin b - \sin a}{b-a}$$

Since $\cos c < 1$ for $c \in (0,\pi/2)$, it follows that $\frac{\sin b - \sin a}{b-a} < 1$, so $\sin b - \sin a < b - a$.

For the left half, pick $f = \tan$, a similar argument leads you to $\tan b - \tan a > b - a$.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to see this. we will use the following facts:

(a) the graph of $y = \sin x, 0 \le x \le \pi/2$ is concave down,

(b) the graph of $y = \tan x, 0 \le x \le \pi/2$ is concave up,

(c) tangent to both graphs at $x = 0$ is $y = x.$

if you now compare the slopes of the secant lines of the  graph to the the slope of the tangent, we have $$\frac{\sin b - \sin a}{b - a} < 1  < \frac{\tan b - \tan a}{b - a} \text{ for } 0 < a < b < \pi/2.  $$